# Custom Selector control does not update after ItemsSource has been set?

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, selector

I've put together a custom control in WPF in C# based on the Selector primitive:

```
public class PadControl : Selector
{
    private const int padWidth = 28;
    private const int padHeight = 18;
    private const int padGap = 5;

    private double _width;
    private double _height;

    static PadControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(PadControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(PadControl), 
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));
    }

    public PadControl()
    {
        
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        _width = constraint.Width;
        _height = constraint.Height;

        return base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
    {
        base.OnRender(dc);

        var numHorz = _width / (padWidth + padGap);
        var numVert = Math.Min(_height / (padHeight + padGap), 16);

        var pen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.0);
        var brush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(192, 192, 192));

        for(int bar = 0; bar < numHorz; bar++)
        {
            for(int track = 0; track < numVert; track++)
            {
                var rect = GetPadRect(bar, track);
                dc.DrawRectangle(brush, pen, rect);
            }
        }

        if (Items == null)
            return;

        brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightYellow);
        var typeface = new Typeface("Tahoma");
        foreach(PadViewModel item in Items)
        {
            var rect = GetPadRect(item.Bar, item.Track);
            dc.DrawRectangle(brush, pen, rect);

            var formatted = new FormattedText(item.Text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, FlowDirection.LeftToRight, typeface, 12, Brushes.Black, 1.0)
            {
                MaxTextWidth = padWidth,
                TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center
            };

            dc.DrawText(formatted, GetPadPoint(item.Bar, item.Track));
        }
    }

    private Rect GetPadRect(int bar, int track)
    {
        var rect = new Rect(bar * (padWidth + padGap) + padGap, track * (padHeight + padGap) + padGap, padWidth, padHeight);
        return rect;
    }

    private Point GetPadPoint(int bar, int track)
    {
        var point = new Point(bar * (padWidth + padGap) + padGap, track * (padHeight + padGap) + padGap);
        return point;
    }
}
```

This draws as I'd like it, but it doesn't draw the items until I resize the control.

When the control renders for the first time, it doesn't render any Items as that is empty. Items is populated indirectly with this:

```
<controls:PadControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Pads}"/>
```

The problem is, I don't see an update come through after ItemsSource has been set. So the question is, how do I attach an event handler to catch this? Do I attach it to Items or to ItemsSource?

Comment: Be aware that the Size passed to MeasureOverride may have Width and/or Height set to `double.PositiveInfinity`. You should not use those values (and hence not override MeasureOverride). Instead, use the RenderSize property.

Comment: Use UpdateLayout()  as in here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ffcf6c99-d1ef-4ce5-94a2-ae1cfba63ba2/how-to-force-wpf-uielement-to-repaint?forum=wpf

Comment: I know about the UpdateLayout call, however my questions is *when* do I call UpdateLayout?

Comment: Does the `Pads` collection implement INotifyCollectionChanged?

Comment: It's an ObservableCollection which does implement INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: You can override `OnItemsSourceChanged`, check for `INotifyCollectionChanged` in the new value and attach an event handler there.

Comment: try :  `ItemsSource="{Binding Pads , UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to override OnItemsSourceChanged as described by Keith Stein in the comments above.